# How to set AuthorizationHandlerContext.User

Tags: c#, asp.net

I created an authorization based on [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-6.0), and at one point in the `AuthorizationHandler`, `AuthorizationHandlerContext.User` is used:

```cs
using System.Security.Claims;
using AuthorizationPoliciesSample.Policies.Requirements;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;

namespace AuthorizationPoliciesSample.Policies.Handlers;

public class MinimumAgeHandler : AuthorizationHandler<MinimumAgeRequirement>
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(
        AuthorizationHandlerContext context, MinimumAgeRequirement requirement)
    {
        var dateOfBirthClaim = context.User.FindFirst(
            c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.DateOfBirth && c.Issuer == "http://contoso.com");

        if (dateOfBirthClaim is null)
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        var dateOfBirth = Convert.ToDateTime(dateOfBirthClaim.Value);
        int calculatedAge = DateTime.Today.Year - dateOfBirth.Year;
        if (dateOfBirth > DateTime.Today.AddYears(-calculatedAge))
        {
            calculatedAge--;
        }

        if (calculatedAge >= requirement.MinimumAge)
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

It's nice that this value is not null, but where does it come from? How do I fill in my data to make this authorization useful? I've read the the "Security and Identity" pages and I'm really not clear on that.

Comment: Hi, can you please tell me how have you added your policies in your startup.cs or program.cs file? I have the very same code but somehow it's not working. I got some unessecary info from `AuthorizationHandlerContext context` and I can't get the policy that I set in my [Authorize(policy="example")] on top of my class/method...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To hook into the authorization header, an implementation of `AuthenticationHandler` is needed.

```
public class UserAuthenticationHandler : AuthenticationHandler<UserAuthenticationOptions>
    {
        public const string Schema = "Basic";
        private const string HeaderAuthorization = "Authorization";

        public UserAuthenticationHandler(
            IOptionsMonitor<UserAuthenticationOptions> options,
            ILoggerFactory logger,
            UrlEncoder encoder,
            ISystemClock clock)
            : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
        {
        }

        protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
        {
            if (!Request.Headers.ContainsKey(HeaderAuthorization))
            {
                return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Unauthorized - no \"" + HeaderAuthorization + "\" header found.");
            }

            // get the value of the authorization header
            string authorizationHeader = Request.Headers[HeaderAuthorization];
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(authorizationHeader))
            {
                return AuthenticateResult.NoResult();
            }

            // snip the schema if it is present
            if (authorizationHeader.StartsWith(Schema, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                authorizationHeader = authorizationHeader[Schema.Length..];
            }

            // now delegate the actual validation of the string
            try
            {
                return ValidateToken(authorizationHeader.Trim());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return AuthenticateResult.Fail(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        protected AuthenticateResult ValidateToken(string token)
        {
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new List<Claim> {new(ClaimTypes.Name, token)}, Scheme.Name);
            var principal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, Array.Empty<string>());
            var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(principal, Scheme.Name);
            return AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket);
        }
    }

    public class UserAuthenticationOptions : AuthenticationSchemeOptions
    {
    }
```

And then register it in during the `Startup` like this:

```
services.AddAuthentication(UserAuthenticationHandler.Schema).AddScheme<UserAuthenticationOptions, UserAuthenticationHandler>(UserAuthenticationHandler.Schema, null);
```